# youtube Embed player customisation

Tags: iframe, youtube

Tried different method to customise(hide YouTube title,logo etc). But still not working. My goal was to hide the title top bar primarily. So looking for some guidance if this is possible at the current time?

*Tried css method,iframe viewport method and some other

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a solution since youtube deprecated the parameter showinfo, you can use html and css.

First, you have to put the youtube iframe in a div:

```
<div class="frame-container">
   <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

Next, you must increase the size of the frame so that it is outside the browser window, and then align it in the centre, since youtube only tries to centre the video and keeps its logos on the sides, this trick should work.

```
.frame-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */  
    padding-top: 25px;
    width: 300%; /* enlarge beyond browser width */
    left: -100%; /* center */
}

.frame-container iframe {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

and finally, to prevent everything from stretching because of the size, you put it inside a wrapper.

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="frame-container">
      <iframe></iframe>
   </div>
</div>

.wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
   max-width: 100%;
}
```

EDIT 1: In case you want to disable suggested video and just allow pause, you have to replace the url with:

In that case, you have to replace the youtube url with:

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID?playlist=VIDEOID&loop=1
```

When the video is looped, the suggested videos will be disabled, and even with the controls disabled you can pause the video by clicking on the video.

Comment: THANK YOU. Thumbnail is not aligned at all. Kinda looks weird.                   It does hide title and logo but hides the control also. WHICH IS FINE FOR NOW. But while pausing the video, it gives suggested videos. Any ways we can hide suggested video? All we need is the video to be played with pause control if possible( ofcourse without any youtube info)